# How to add IUserDialogs to Maui IOC Add Singleton for Acr.UserDialogs

Tags: mvvm, inversion-of-control, maui

I'm converting app to Maui.  Old IOS through TinyIOC/FreshMvvm was

```
    FreshMvvm.FreshIOC.Container.Register<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);
```

so how should that look in MauiProgram.cs using built in IOC?

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRestService, RestService>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICacheManager, CacheManager>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs,UserDialogs.Instance>();
```

Says Instance does not exist in the type UserDialogs.
and

```
   builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs,UserDialogs>();
```

Says Static types cannot be used as type Arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to add IUserDialogs to Maui IOC Add Singleton for Acr.UserDialogs

I tried to achieve it by following step:

MauiProgram.cs:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(...)
            .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnApplicationCreate(app => UserDialogs.Init(app)));
#endif
            });

#if ANDROID
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(UserDialogs.Instance);
#endif

       return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static IUserDialogs UserDialogs;
    public App(IUserDialogs userDialogs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UserDialogs = userDialogs;

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Page.xaml.cs to use it:

```cs
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.UserDialogs.Alert("sss");
        
       //UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("ss");
    }
}
```

However, this error occurs:[image]

But I have added the code `UserDialogs.Init(app)`, it still has the error above. I added breakpoints and found that It always executes this line of code first: `builder.Services.AddSingleton(UserDialogs.Instance);` instead of `UserDialogs.Init(app)`.

Of course, if not add Singleton, use UserDialogs directly:

```cs
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //App.UserDialogs.Alert("sss");

        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("ss");
    }
}
```

It [works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4lW8.png), and also will execute `UserDialogs.Init(app)`.

I hope these can help you.

**Update:**

> How is your UserDialogs resolving in your ContentPage?

You need to initialize UserDialogs: [way1(in MauiProgram.cs)](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/sample/Sample/MauiProgram.cs#L22) or way2(in MainActivity.cs):

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    UserDialogs.Init(this);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Update2:**

I found the way to solve it! The codes of `App.xaml.cs` and `Page.xaml.cs` above remain unchanged. And Change MauiProgram.cs:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
//initialize UserDialogs here 
#if ANDROID
            UserDialogs.Init(()=>Platform.CurrentActivity);
#endif

        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if ANDROID
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(UserDialogs.Instance);
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

It works well and can call `builder.Services.AddSingleton(UserDialogs.Instance)` normally.

Comment: I am using this in a library first then including into my final app.  I don't understand how your UserDialogs.Instance is getting resolved at compile time?  I receive an error CS1061 IUserDialogs does not contain a definition for Instance.  Since it's not part of the core interface.  How is your UserDialogs resolving in your ContentPage?

Comment: The issue really seems to be trying to use AddSingleton on an Interface/Service where it has an Instance that is created during startup of Platform specific code.  Since that is null when it hits the builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance); then it wont accept it.  So how is that done?  Can it be added to IOC after that time of instantiation?

Comment: @tallman It can call `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);` normally! And I updated the answer.

Comment: Hurray!!!! Your change worked.  Thanks for spending time reviewing this as it's a big timesaver for me having to recode a bunch of my app!  I'll test the other answer provided as well.