# How to open ContentPage with parameter in Shell

Tags: shell, xaml, xamarin.forms, tabbar

gays!
I use Xamarin.Forms, Shell and want to make TabBar to open pages

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Dictionary" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:WordPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Tools" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:ToolsPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

But a problem: class WordPage has next signature
`public WordPage(bool _transl)` and I unable to open this page by xaml due parameter. I didn't find any examples how to create TabBar in C#. May be anybody knows how to build TabBar in C# or any another idea how to open pages with parameter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you need this parameter?  Under what circumstances would the value change?

Comment: Page loads data from database depending on parameter. It is dictionary, if parameter is true, dictionary is Ua->En, if parameter is false, dictionary is En->Ua

Comment: Where does the parameter come from in the first place? You won't be able to pass it to the page via constructor argument. Unfortunately, you will have to resort to some kind of service and the *Service Locator* pattern by resolving the service inside of the page class using a DI container.

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to pass this argument with xaml, therefore I'm asking the C# construction. I don't understand the question about source of parameter. Could you give some example of this container?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274870/how-to-add-iuserdialogs-to-maui-ioc-add-singleton-for-acr-userdialogs/76279710#76279710)?